# SharedPreferences for serialization?

Tags: android, serialization, sharedpreferences

I'm rather new to Android development, and am trying to learn with a bit of a hobby project. My app has a relatively small amount of state that needs to be stored for the main Activity in order for the app to resume properly. Moreover, since my app syncs with a webapp, I already have JSON-based serialization logic included for all the state that I might want to save. Is it a good use of SharedPreferences to store relatively small (~ a few KiB) strings that serialize objects? Would it be better to just use internal storage and write out to a text file? Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared prefs is a good way to save that kind of data. I don't know what would be better about using a file in internal storage. (If it was a lot of data, I'd consider using a file on the sdcard.)

Answer (score 0):

Shared prefs are used to store name values pairs for example like preferences. The format that is used to store these data is a simple xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<string name="id1">text1</string>
<string name="id2">textb</string>
<string name="id3">text</string>
</map>
```

So when your string is only a few kb large the resulting (xml-)overhead to data relation isn't as well as when storing large strings in the same structure. 
In this case storing small sets of data is more efficient using for example a simple JSON structure (You use json libs anyway?!).

Another disadvantage is that you can't access the xml files as a java File object so you can't delete them.